# Pause downloads in AFNetworking - objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlrequest, afnetworking

How to pause downloads in AFNetworking? I'm downloading file with AFHTTPRequestOperation, but there is only cancel method. How to pause and resume it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really looking for is [AFDownloadRequestOperation](https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation) which will allow you to pause/resume during a download.

Answer (score 1):

`AFURLConnectionOperation Class` has a `pause`, `resume`.

check out this:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h

Also you must add `#import "AFURLConnectionOperation.h"`.

AFHTTPRequestOperation Class is inherited by AFURLConnectionOperation Class.

Comment: This pause/resume is related to the NSOperations queue on which the AFURLConnectionOperation is based. i.e. Once a download is in progress, then it can't be paused. I'm not sure if this is what @Timur was asking.